# Get a list of all files present in the same directory - JS for browser

Tags: javascript, html, file, cloud

I'm not sure and got the feeling that the answer is somewhere here but I can't find it ...

Well, I want to get a list of all the files that are in the same directory as the web page. The objective is to print them.

For now, I found out how to get the address of the HTML file. See :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <Title>All files</Title>
    </head>

    <body>
        Link list
        <ul id="List">
            <!-- <li><a href="Example.zip">Example.zip</a></li> -->
        </ul>

        <script>

            var locarray = window.location.href.split("/");
            delete locarray[(locarray.length - 1)];
            var ActualPath = locarray.join("/");

            console.log("We are in : " + ActualPath);

            // TODO : fill the 'files' array

             files.forEach(file => {
                 console.log(file);
             });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for spending time on this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a certain time. I can now say that it is impossible. You have to use some server-side language like PHP or JS with a framework under Node.js.

Comment: It is not impossible in browsers that support the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).